# Formal notation for number of rows/columns in a matrix

Tags: notation, matrices

Is there a generally accepted formal notation for denoting the number of columns a matrix has (e.g to use in pseudocode/algorithm environment in LaTeX)? Something I could use in the description of an algorithm like:

```
if horizontaldim(V) > x then
end if
```

or

```
if size(V,2) > x then 
end if
```

or should I just use a description like

```
if number of columns in V > x then
end if
```

Comment: I've got the case where I need the number of rows and columns of several matrices quite often in one figure. Furthermore, I don't have much space for operator names like `rows` and `cols`. Sometimes $\#$ is used for the number of elements of a set. Applied to a matrix it could also denote the number of elements. What elements? One could adopt the syntax of the `size`-operator and write $\#_1 V$ for the number of rows and $\#_2 V$ for the number of columns. This notation would also work for multi-dimensional arrays with $\#_i V$ where $i$ is the index position. In the matrix case $i=1$ or $2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None that I know of, but I've seen numerical linear algebra books (e.g. Golub and Van Loan) just say something like $V\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ for a matrix V with m rows and n columns, and then use m and n in the following algorithm description.

MATLAB notation, which some other people use, just says rows(V) and columns(V).

Comment: Might be obvious, but for completeness' sake: if V is a complex matrix, then it should be $V\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ .